# Using a node-value in a role

Tags: chef-infra

I have a role, in which I need to use a value that is specific to that node:

```
default_attributes "varnish" => {
  "listen_address" => node['ipaddress'],
  "listen_port" => "80",
  # ...
}
```

This, however flunks: `NameError: undefined local variable or method`node' for role[caching_server]:Chef::Role`.

Is the "role" evaluated on the chef-client? Do I need to access this variable in a somewhat different way? Or should this attribute be defined outside of a role instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Role is static, and is evaluated during upload time.

Thats why roles are seen as an evil: global, static thing and you cannot version them.

Community is following now the Berkshelf way (http://www.slideshare.net/opscode/the-berkshelf-way-20882903, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYt0E84kYUI).

One of the principles is too push down logic from your role to recipe where you have much better control of how the node is configured.

1. You build your application cookbook, e.g. myface
2. Create recipe named after your role: app_proxy.rb. That is your integration recipe.
3. Override all needed attributes (as you did in role) with:
   node.override['varnish']['listen_address'] = node['ipaddress'] 
   node.override['varnish']['listen_port'] = "80"
   ...
4. Move run_list from role  to that recipe

Comment: Nice idea for "Role Recipes", just ran across this post with the same concept: http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/11/19/chef-roles-arent-evil/